# zabbix user unable to execute sudo mysqladmin ping

Tags: linux, mysql, zabbix, user-permissions, zabbix-agent

I am trying to check whether MySql is up by using a UserParameter in zabbix.

UserParameter looks like this.

> UserParameter=mysql.ping,sudo mysqladmin ping | grep -c alive | wc -l

When I execute `mysqladmin ping | grep -c alive` in the server, it is giving me the correct response.

> #mysqladmin ping | grep alive | wc -l
>
> 1

But when I try to run the command as a zabbix user, It is giving the following error:

> # sudo -u zabbix sudo mysqladmin ping | grep alive | wc -l
>      mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
>      error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using >password: NO)'
>
> 0

Just running the following works:

> # sudo -u zabbix mysqladmin

..listing out various commands in mysqladmin

I have added zabbix to the sudoers list, requiring no password.

The issue is just for MySql, all other UserParameters (e.g. mail,load etc.) are working fine.

Comment: You probably have `requiretty` set in `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Actually, it looks like you don't need `sudo` when running the command as `zabbix` user. Try `sudo -u zabbix mysqladmin ping | grep alive | wc -l`

Comment: I have commented out `requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers`, so this should not cause any problem. When I tried `sudo -u zabbix mysqladmin ping | grep alive | wc -l`, I got the same error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go through all this hassle. You can configure your my.cnf and zabbix agent using UserParameter=mysql.status.

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
  https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40870
```

Comment: I have tried this method resulted in the same error shown above.
I am curious on why `mysql.ping` won't work.

Comment: then it must be some permission issue, check your selinux configuration, look into the logs and see if you find anything related.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Finally I ended up doing `service mysqld status | grep -c running`